# PHP split string into integer, string and special character

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I need to split this format of strings `CF12:10` into array like below,

`[0] => CF, [1] => 12, [2] => 10`

Numbers and String of the provided string can be any length. I have found the php `preg_match` function but don't know how to make regular expression for my case. Any solution would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex to match the individual parts:

```
^(\D+)(\d+):(.*)$
```

It matches start of string, some number of non-digit characters (`\D+`), followed by some number of digits (`\d+`), a colon and some number of characters after the `:` and before end-of-line. In PHP you can use `preg_match` to then find all the matching groups:

```
$input = 'CF12:10';
preg_match('/^(\D+)(\d+):(.*)$/', $input, $matches);
array_shift($matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => CF
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 10
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mvJYP)

Comment: This is what i expected, Thanks lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code if it helps you

```
 $str = 'C12:10';
 $arr = preg_match('~^(.*?)(\d+):(.*)~m', $str, $matches);
 array_shift($matches);                                                   
 echo '<pre>';print_r($matches);
```

Comment: You can explode with : first like this. $arr = explode(‘:’,$string) and then run the above code on $arr[0] and $arr[1] will already be equal to 10